# Multiple Layout base locale - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, locale

My application is multiple language like:

```
activity_al_main.xml(en)
activity_al_main.xml(en-rUS)
```

And I set like bellow in `activity`:

```
View view = SetCustomLayouts.setCustomLayout(MainActivityMou.this, "en-rUS", R.layout.activity_al_main);
this.setContentView(view);
```

And:

```
public class SetCustomLayouts {
    public static View setCustomLayout(Context context, String LangID, int layout) {
        Context contexts = ContextWrapper.wrap(context, LangID);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        return Objects.requireNonNull(inflater).inflate(contexts.getResources().getLayout(layout), null);
    }
}
```

But get me bellow error:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0d001e
```

**Notice:** I don't have problem with `en`, `sp`, `fr`, `tr`.... but when I use from `en-rUS` get me error.

Comment: try using "en-rus"

Comment: @ Jeel Vankhede.Not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved my problem:

```
public class ContextWrapper extends android.content.ContextWrapper {

    private ContextWrapper(Context base) {
        super(base);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static android.content.ContextWrapper wrap(Context context, String language) {
        Configuration config = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
        if (language != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(language)) {
            Locale locale;
            if (language.contains("-")) {
                String[] arrSplit = language.split("-r");
                String lang = arrSplit[0];
                String country = arrSplit[1];
                locale = new Locale(lang, country);
            } else {
                locale = new Locale(language);
            }
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                setSystemLocale(config, locale);
            } else {
                setSystemLocaleLegacy(config, locale);
            }
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
                context = context.createConfigurationContext(config);
            } else {
                context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            }
        } else {
            Locale locale = new Locale("en");
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                setSystemLocale(config, locale);
            } else {
                setSystemLocaleLegacy(config, locale);
            }
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
                context = context.createConfigurationContext(config);
            } else {
                context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            }
        }
        return new ContextWrapper(context);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private static void setSystemLocaleLegacy(Configuration config, Locale locale) {
        config.locale = locale;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    private static void setSystemLocale(Configuration config, Locale locale) {
        config.setLocale(locale);
    }

}
```

Comment: Consider adding some description about solution you've found, it'll help others in future